# Can you connect to a SQL server database for synchronization?

Tags: objectbox

I have a SQL database on a server and would like to use objectbox to manage it using the sync functionality

Comment: What did you try to do how exactly and what was the observed result as opposed to what you had expected exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Without writing additional code, ObjectBox Sync clients can only connect and sync with an ObjectBox Sync server.

There are more details at https://objectbox.io/sync/ and https://sync.objectbox.io/

Comment: I've been trying to get support form objectbox by emailing requesting objectbox's best practices for writing that additional code or for questions regarding sync server security pricing etc and instead been basically told to just take a hike.  Can you provide some guidance to best practices regarding interfacing objectbox with our back end?